# I want some boxes to fill everything, Im using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want my fluid boxes to take all the content. This is what I get now:

[image]

And this is what I am looking for:

[image]

I am using the Twitter bootstrap.

Here is the jsfiddle, exactly like my layout shows:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jUQEc/
```

Current html markup:

```
<div class="container-narrow">

      <h4 class="title">Featured Companies</h4>

      <div class="row-fluid" id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
        <div class="span6 item">
          <h4 class="title">Company Details</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 item">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 item">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 item">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check here http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Andrevinsky, I updated the quetion with the jsfiddle.

Comment: 6 + 3 + 3 + 4 = 16

Are you using 16-column grid?

Consider your left part of the desired structure to contain
span6>div.row-fluid>((div.row-fluid>div.span12)+(div.row-fluid>div.span12))

Comment: No shit Sherlock. I know that. I want the first three boxes to show in a line, and the fourth one to be under them. The illustration is not exactly like the code.

Comment: Amar, you can nest div.row-fluid>(div.spanX+div.spanY) to infinity.
You're looking for:
row 1:( column 1: (row 1: ( column 1: 100%), row 2: ( column 1: 100%)), column 2: (right part))
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 0):

You should put a width on the 3rd box and then float it right. If it fits, it will sneak up and fill in the space you are looking for. Perhaps you should brush up on how floats work and take a look at how this applies to divs in bootstrap. Hope this helps!